# Hibernate: is there the way to use "like" expression in filters?

Tags: hibernate, filter

I use hibernate filters massively, but face the problem with using **like** expression together with '%' literals. So, I can use this:

```
@Filter(name = "filterOnTS", condition = "lower(m.name) like :carName)"),
```

but cannot this:

```
@Filter(name = "filterOnTS", condition = "lower(m.name) like '%:carName%')"),
```

As in this case Hibernate regards **%:carName%** as the literal. Can I override this behaviour somehow?

Answer (score 1):

`@Filter(name = "filterOnTS", condition = "lower(m.name) like "+"%"+carName+"%)")`,